# Connect MS OLAP with Java

Tags: java, olap, olap-cube, olap4j

I have a data source which has a provider MSOLAP I want to connect to this source via java based application. I used the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Load the driver
    Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");

    // Connect
    final Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection(
                // This is the SQL Server service end point.
                "jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost:81/mondrian/xmla"

                // Tells the XMLA driver to use a SOAP request cache layer.
                // We will use an in-memory static cache.
                + ";Cache=org.olap4j.driver.xmla.cache.XmlaOlap4jNamedMemoryCache"

                // Sets the cache name to use. This allows cross-connection
                // cache sharing. Don't give the driver a cache name and it
                // disables sharing.
                + ";Cache.Name=MyNiftyConnection"

                            // Some cache performance tweaks.
                            // Look at the javadoc for details.
                            + ";Cache.Mode=LFU;Cache.Timeout=600;Cache.Size=100",

                    // XMLA is over HTTP, so BASIC authentication is used.
                    null,
                    null);

    // We are dealing with an olap connection. we must unwrap it.
    final OlapConnection olapConnection = connection.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);

    // Check if it's all groovy
    ResultSet databases = olapConnection.getMetaData().getDatabases();
    databases.first();
    System.out.println(
            olapConnection.getMetaData().getDriverName()
                    + " -> "
                    + databases.getString(1));

    // Done
    connection.close();
}
```

I get the class `OlapConnection` is not compiled. I have two questions: 1- I am using maven to build this test and it is not showing errors why would this class not be found?

2- is there any other way to connect to MSOLAP without using olap4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how you connect remotely to an XMLA service. Start by reading [this code](https://code.google.com/p/olap4j-demo/source/browse/trunk/src/org/devdonkey/olap4j/demo/XmlaDriverConnectDemo.java), and then you'll need to edit the connection string.

In SSAS, the connection string should look something like this:

```
jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll;Catalog=myCatalog
```

Comment: I have tried the example you indicated but still the maven dependency could not provide OlapConnection class. I updated the code

Comment: If your problem is with Maven, then that's a separate issue, not related to olap4j at all. I'd recommend making sure that you're including both org.olap4j:olap4j and org.olap4j:olap4j-xmla as dependencies.